# mysql text search OR syntax

Tags: php, mysql

I have

```
SELECT * FROM hnurl WHERE title LIKE('%text1%')
```

How do I extend this to also add in things `LIKE('%text2%')?` within the same query results?

Comment: It depends on your need. It can be an AND, it can be an OR.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried:

```
SELECT * FROM hnurl WHERE title LIKE '%text1%' OR title LIKE '%text2%';
```

Comment: @David19801: In MySQL `||` also works. See the documentation: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/logical-operators.html#operator_or  Your problem must be something else.

Answer (score 2):

Use `OR` if you want rows where *either or both* strings are found:

```
SELECT * FROM hnurl
WHERE title LIKE '%text1%'
OR title LIKE '%text2%'
```

Use `AND`  if you want rows where *both* strings are found:

```
SELECT * FROM hnurl
WHERE title LIKE '%text1%'
AND title LIKE '%text2%'
```

Sidenote: You may also wish to consider using a [full-text search](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/fulltext-search.html) or an external  text search engine to improve the performance of your queries.

Comment: to use an external engine, would I have to put my entire database with them?  What would hte benefit of full text search be over what I am doing here?

Comment: @David19801: The benefit? It's faster. Much, much faster.

Answer (score 0):

You could add

```
... OR title LIKE '%text2%'
```

Answer (score 0):

It is also possible with MySQL REGEXP, see the most simplified examples at http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/regexp.html, something like:

```
SELECT * FROM hnurl
WHERE title REGEXP 'text(1|2)'
```

Variations possible.